# Connecting oracle 12c remotely

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I am pl/sql developer and does not have any experience in DBA. I installed an oracle linux virtual copy with oracle 12c preinstalled for learning and testing purposes. I have sql developer on my host machine and through it I connect to the DB on virtual as sys user, at this point everything is fine. But when I try connecting to the DB through SCOTT, HR or any other user that I created before it give me this error message:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

    ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
    01017. 00000 -  "invalid username/password; logon denied"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
    Vendor code 1017
```

Notes:

1. I am very sure that username and password is correct.
2. This denied access appear only when I try connecting with DB from host machine with non-sys user.
3. when trying connecting through sqlplus on virtual machine all users connects without any problems.
4. I Unlock the user and changed it's password before trying.

How can I solve this problem

**EDITED**

connection properties:

connection_name : normal_user

username : SCOTT

pass : oracle

connection type : basic

role : default

hostname, port ,SID  I am sure they are true.

when I execute this query `select * from all_users where username = 'SCOTT'`
result is: 
USERNAME : SCOTT

USER_ID : 109

CREATED : 07-JUL-14

COMMON : NO

ORACLE_MAINTAINED : N

Comment: Do you still have the SYSDBA role selected in the connection configuration?

Comment: make sure you're connecting to the right service, the 12c database could have two services, one for the container database and another one for the pluggable, which is where your SCOTT/HR schemas would be installed

Comment: thatjeffsmith,
I note this issue, when I create user I used pluggable DB, SCOTT and HR users are also in pluggable DB

Comment: Alex Pool,
I used all possible roles, normal and sysdba, but no response.

Comment: show us your connection properties please

Comment: @thatjeffsmith please note EDITED section above

Comment: you can't use SID on 12c, you have to use SERVICE. if you use SID, you'll go into the container database

Comment: but I can connect sys user by SID why this does not work with other users. 
@thatjeffsmith can you give more clarification about this point please ?

Comment: bc the sys user is going to the container, where it exists...SYS is in the container and in every PDB. your schema user, isn't in the container. it's only in the pluggable, which can only be accessed via a SERVICE